# Is there a way to tell log4j to remove or replace newlines in every one of its logging calls?

Tags: log4j

Is there a setting to tell log4j to makes sure any messages passed to its logging methods have their newlines removed or replaced with some special character in order to guarantee that every logging method only prints out a single-line in the log file?

Bonus question: is there a best practice for what to replace newlines with for log file readability?  Perhaps the string "\n"?

Comment: Which version of log4j you are using?

Comment: Seems log2j support that, log4j does not.